# Windows no longer booting after copying partition using Gparted

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, gparted

I originally had 3 partitions on my hard disk:

Vista

Storage

Seven

I just used Gparted to delete the Vista partition and copy the Seven partition onto it. I was going to see if it would boot. If it did, I would have deleted the Seven partition and extended the Storage partition to absorb that space.

The copy of the partition was successful, I can see the files via explorer when I boot my Windows 7 disc. But neither copy of seven is booting at startup at the moment, I'm getting "Operating System not found".

Problem now is nothing is booting. I have tried putting my Windows 7 disc in and repairing but it's still not booting.

Can anyone help? If I really really need to I could get hold of an external hard disk, back up and start fresh, but this is a last resort, I need to use this computer to work on tomorrow. I don't want to be stuck reinstalling windows and all my software on it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check that the right partition is active.

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: You can use Gparted live.  According to the documentation, you make a partition active in Gpartd by setting the Boot flag.  See http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-manage-partition-flags